# Extract Child XML into a List (of child elements) Using SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a variable that contains a lit of elements in a collection.  I want to a list of the children...1 in each row...but this gives me a single row

- I have tried different variants...to no success

[image]

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<MeterImportDataItems>
    <MeterImportDataItem>
        <MeterId>-1</MeterId>
        <GlobalId>cd5116fa-15f9-48c7-946b-1b199550d014</GlobalId>
        <DeviceId>5029</DeviceId>
        <MeterName>GREER CENTRAL POINT</MeterName>
        <MeterNumber>0989745-10</MeterNumber>
        <MeterTypeName>Orifice</MeterTypeName>
        <RunStatusCategory>Active</RunStatusCategory>
        <SystemCategoryId>2</SystemCategoryId>
        <SystemCategoryName>Intrastate</SystemCategoryName>
        <DataSourceName>Meter Dashboard</DataSourceName>
    </MeterImportDataItem>
    <MeterImportDataItem>
        <MeterId>-1</MeterId>
        <GlobalId>26f07f46-c506-4c06-bba9-9ae0e09a72fd</GlobalId>
        <DeviceId>0</DeviceId>
        <MeterName>TL MCCRARY 14-11H CRP</MeterName>
        <MeterNumber>4523401</MeterNumber>
        <MeterTypeName>Orifice</MeterTypeName>
        <RunStatusCategory>Temporarily Disconnected</RunStatusCategory>
        <SystemCategoryId>2</SystemCategoryId>
        <SystemCategoryName>Intrastate</SystemCategoryName>
        <DataSourceName>Meter Dashboard</DataSourceName>
    </MeterImportDataItem>
</MeterImportDataItems>'

SELECT
    C.value('MeterId[1]','INT') AS MeterId
    , C.value('GlobalId[1]','UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS GlobalId
    , C.value('DeviceId[1]','INT') AS DeviceId
    , C.value('MeterName[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS MeterName
    , C.value('MeterNumber[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS MeterNumber
    , C.value('MeterTypeName[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS MeterTypeName
    , C.value('RunStatusCategory[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS RunStatusCategory
    , C.value('SystemCategoryId[1]','INT') AS SystemCategoryId
    , C.value('SystemCategoryName[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS SystemCategoryName
    , C.value('DataSourceName[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS DataSourceName
FROM @XML.nodes('MeterImportDataItems/MeterImportDataItem') AS T(C)
FOR XML PATH('MeterImportDataItem'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: Instead of simply voting it down...how about a comment as to WHY?

Comment: There isn't much to add to your own answer, and there is nothing wrong with answering your own question. Possibly someone downvoted because they thought it too simple. Perhaps elaborate the answer a bit about what `.nodes` and `.query` are doing, so that anyone who finds this later will understand

Comment: @Charlieface OMG...!!!  I never thought I would live long enough to see a truly positive & constructive comment on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out.

```
SELECT 
    T.c.query('.') AS MeterImportDataItem  
FROM   @XML.nodes('/MeterImportDataItems/MeterImportDataItem') T(c)
```